# Confusion about HTTPS --> How is SSL handshake happing

Tags: ssl, https

I've always been an end consumer of HTTPS and have never really understood it that well but am looking to change that.

I am calling a RESTful web service over HTTPS. For example...

```
curl -X GET \
  https://myCompanydns/rest/connect/v1.4/myEndpoint
```

With all my requests I send a basic authentication header i.e a username and password.

When I make these calls via my application I was expecting to have to add a certificate into like a jks (which I've had to do in the past) but on this occasion I've found that I can call the HTTPS web service without that.

For HTTPS to work I believe there is an SSL handshake? How is that happening successfully is this scenario without a jks?

Again, sorry for this beginner type question.

Comment: In a **TLS** handshake, each part may want to identify the other. Each party may have a certificate, signed by some CA (or self signed), that it can send to the other. Due to some cryptographic constructions, each party can verify the other party certificate and either accept the CA that issued the certificate (so any certificate will work, no beforehand configuration needed except having the CA certificate locally in trust store) or accept the specific certificate given (whitelisting) which means it has been exchanged beforehand out-of-band and will need maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a `https://...` request the client needs to verify that the servers certificate is the expected one - and not some man in the middle. This is done (among other things) by making sure that the servers certificate was issued by a trusted certificate authority (CA). Which CA is trusted is setup in the local trust store (i.e. local to the client). In the above call where no explicit trust store is given `curl` is using its default trust store. In the case where you've explicitly gave a jks you've provided the application with a specific trust store it should use.

For more on how the server certificates gets validated see [SSL Certificate framework 101: How does the browser actually verify the validity of a given server certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity).

Comment: ....default trust store .... does that mean that I have trusted that certificate before on my machine for my call to be working?

Comment: @Richie: please read the details I've linked to on how certificate validation works.  You trust the CA which issued the servers certificate. It does not require that you trust each server certificate explicitly.

Comment: Ok now I’ve read it properly and have a better understanding. The root CA of my rest URL is digicert. So I guess the conclusion I reach is on my local computer my trust store trusts digicert andvthats why I don’t need to define a trust store inside a jks

Comment: "It does not require that you trust each server certificate explicitly. " On some other OS, like Debian, when there is an update of the system trust store, depending on the configuration, you may be prompted to specify if you allow adding such and such new CAs.